# Web API Error - This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

Tags: azure, google-chrome, asp.net-web-api, angular5, mixed-content

We have deployed the api on azure and trying to consume in our web app written in angular 5. However when we try to consume the api we are getting following errors.

> **Chrome** Mixed Content: The page at 'https://somedevapp.azurewebsites.net/#/managesomething' was loaded
>   over HTTPS,  but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
>   'http://admindevapp.azurewebsites.net/api/data/getdata'.  This request
>   has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
>
> **Firefox** Blocked loading mixed active content

Is this issue related to CORS? How to resolve this issue?

Any help on this appreciated!

Comment: The Chrome error message has explained exactly what the problem is, and how you need to fix it.

Comment: You can add the domain of your API to allowed resources in your html head. And like the error said: use https

Comment: @duskwuff Yes So we need to consume all APIs with https protocol only. But do we need to fix in angular from where we are consuming APIs OR from web api side also ?

Comment: @SimonFranzen can you give example how to add domain of APIs in allowed resources in HTML head ?

Comment: Google: CORS allow Domain . Sorry I am on the way .....

Answer (score 124, accepted):

If your web app is being hosted over HTTPs as you've indicated, then all external resources it is consuming (CDN, scripts, CSS files, API calls) should also use SSL and be secured through HTTPs. Think about it. It would defeat the purpose of your app being secure, if your app was in turn making insecure requests to an API.

You can either therefore:

1. As Chrome suggests, change your API calls to use HTTPs (**recommended**)
2. Use HTTP instead of HTTPs
3. Add the following `meta` tag to your `<head>` element in your HTML:

   `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests" />`

More information about this can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/upgrade-insecure-requests.

Comment: Note, this only works if the requested resource supports HTTPS, in which case, just use HTTPS to begin with.

Comment: Is this the recommended way to prevent blocking the content according to the security standards or using https forcefully ?

Answer (score 20):

Use this ---- Add in your head section
I will try this with my weather application & now it's working fine

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

Comment: You should just add this piece of code to your index.html in Angular

Answer (score 12):

only add this on header section.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

Comment: You should just add this piece of code to your index.html in Angular

Answer (score 8):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

you can use this only if your resource API supports the HTTPS request.

example: "http://ip-api.com/json" and "https://ip-api.com/json" both will not return the same response if "ip-api.com" doesn't support HTTPS requests.

Answer (score 5):

The meta tag below helps to prevent Chrome complaining about HTTP request made. I was working on a class projects (a weather app) and the API call over HTTP and adding an S to the HTTP call doesn't help. Since this a project a there no major issue. The meta tag share above by @Medhi Ibrahim does the trick.

```
   <meta 
     http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"   
     content="upgrade-insecure-requests" 
    />
```

Answer (score 2):

i tried to remove the "meta solution" on index.
And removed the "s" on environment.prod.ts

When i sign in " http://app.finoview.com" the api Nestjs works.

But when i try to log in "https://finoview.com", angular works, but the api nestjs doesnt work.

Here is the image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For people using AWS, here is what I did to solve the issue:

```
EC2 -> Load Balancers -> Select the load balancer you are using -> Add a new listener for HTTPS (default port is 443)
```

After that, I just changed the URL from `http:` to `https:`, and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't say when/for how long. If you only want to do this for testing (not in production where you don't control the browser and it's bad for end user's security) and you are using Chrome, you can change this setting:

Settings -> Privacy and Security -> Site settings -> Additional content settings -> Insecure content -> Allowed to show insecure content -> Add [www.BLAH.local](http://www.BLAH.local) (domain that contains the web page you are loading via HTTPS, not the HTTP resource).

[image: Insecure Content configuration in Chrome]