# Flutter Web Mixed Content

Tags: flutter, web, xmlhttprequest, dio, mixed-content

I have flutter app which is working ok in android and ios device.

Now I am trying it on web.
But I'm getting mixed content error.

Error
`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://myhostingweb.com/#/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://mybackendrequestweb.com/some.php'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

I tried some solution, but nothing work.
I'm using for http request dio library

Please help.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does  [XMLHttpRequest error in flutter web](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60191683/10157127) question answer your question?

Comment: No that not error. I think its to calling http in https website.

Comment: You can try [This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52130918/10157127)

Comment: Thanks for your Help. I change my backend http protocol to https. Its solved issue.