# nginx blocked stram video http url over https

Tags: nginx, https, http-live-streaming, nginx-config

I have local website (192.168.1.150) on Nginx and the website have stream video page work with URL `http://187.25.36.26/tv/live.m3u8` (url is HLS stream video on IP static and the server not for me and I do not have access that).

When my website run over http that work perfect on NGINX. But when I use https that block request the URL with this error `request has been blocked the content must be served over https` .

Note : when I use `http://187.25.36.26/images/icon.png` that not block and load image. I mean all types of images or videos are loaded on stream server because their type is media, But the stream URL is blocked because its type is xhr.

I try [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67867883/19773044) code but not work (add meta data to my html page):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

How can I allow to nginx  the http stream url load on my website over https ?