# swagger is not working on load balancer server for .net core API

Tags: .net, swagger

I deployed .net core API on individual servers. I'm able to access end points via Postman working correctly,
but when I try hit load balancer URL and try to use swagger I get the below error,
using .net core 6.

Is this https /http issue?

> **error in console**- This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
>
> Undocumented
> TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: Did you check if this is a CORS issue?

Comment: What is the full error message shown in the Console tab in the browser dev tools?

Comment: error in console- This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: i have addec changes for cors already

Comment: The error implies that Swagger UI is hosted on HTTPS but the API to which the requests are made is on plain HTTP. Is this the case? (Related: [Web API Error - This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52130918/113116))